# Error 500 (Internal Server Error), quanto tento criar uma sessão

Tags: java, http, vraptor

Estou tentando criar uma sessão para um login usando  Java, vRaptor, Hibernate, AngularJS.
Mas quando a sessão vai ser criada recebo essa exceção (`500 (Internal Server Error`)).

Esta é minha classe de sessão usando o vRaptor:

```
@SessionScoped
```

@Any
public class LoginModel implements Serializable {
    private Administrador administrador;

```
public static void LoginModel(String[] arg) {

}

public void login(Administrador administrador) {
    this.administrador = administrador;
}



public boolean isLogado() {
    return administrador != null;
}

public Administrador getLogado() {
    return administrador;
}

public void setLogado(Administrador administrador) {
    this.administrador = administrador;
}

public void logout() {
    this.administrador = null;
}
```

E no meu controler eu tenho o metodo que verifica e cria a sessão :

```
 @Consumes("application/json")
@Post("/verifica-login")
public void verificaLogin(String email, String senha) {
    try {
        Administrador administrador;
        administrador = administradorRepository.login(email, senha);

       //Até essa parte esta tudo certo, o administrador ja foi validado
      // e já foi carregado no objeto administrador, mas quando o comando
      // abaixo (if) é executado eu recebo a exceção. 

        if (administrador != null) {
            loginModel.login(administrador);
        }
        result.use(Results.json()).withoutRoot().from(administrador).serialize();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        result.use(Results.json()).withoutRoot().from(e.getMessage()).serialize();
    }

}
```

Gostaria de saber o que estou fazendo, porque eu li algumas documentações e segui alguns tutorias e aparentemente está certo, mas minha falta de experiência não ajuda nessas horas KKK. Eu estava seguindo um exemplo da Caelum.

Obs:. Não sei para que serve essa anotação @Any, mas estava pedindo ela ou @Default, para funcionar, no tutorial da Caelum pede para adicionar a anotação @Component, mas essa anotação não possui nenhum importação do vraptor ou algo parecido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro era devida a não inicialização da classe LoginModel, o que também causava um erro de retorno nulo de objeto, no final minha classe ficou assim.

```
@Consumes("application/json")
@Post("/verifica-login")
public void verificaLogin(String email, String senha) {
    try {
        Administrador administrador = administradorRepository.login(email, senha);
        LoginModel loginModel = new LoginModel();
        if (administrador != null) {
            loginModel.login(administrador);
        }
        result.use(Results.json()).withoutRoot().from(administrador).serialize();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        result.use(Results.json()).withoutRoot().from(e.getMessage()).serialize();
    }

}
```

Isso resolveu o problema de criar a sessão.